# Update a whole column based on 2 columns of a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

I added a new column to a table. The columns of the table are:

```
Identifier(unique identity but not joinable to the other table)
ClinicalID(int)
senttime(datetime)
orgID(int-new column)
```

I need to update the new column from a different table based on the sent time. 
I should check on what date range the sent time falls and update the orgID accordingly.
Columns of the other table:

```
ClinicalIDentifier
org ID(int) 
old orgID(int)
effectivefromtime
effectivethrutime
```

The issue I am facing is that if the senttime is > effective fromtime of the other table, it displayes the other org IDs of the same ClinicalID where the  senttime is > effective fromtime.

I am stuck at comparing date ranges.

Please let me know if you require any further information

Comment: did you try `between`? `senttime between effectivefromtime and effectivethrutime `

Comment: Yes. I tried. Still the same. It also takes in the values lesser than that and displays nulls when queried with between.

Comment: What I am looking for is like if the sentdate is between two otehr date columns then org Id else old org ID... I have used the case statements for it:
`code`case 
when (op.effectivethrutime is not null and ac.senttime between op.effectivefromtime and op.effectivethrutime) then op.organizationidentifier
when (op.effectivethrutime is not null and ac.senttime < op.effectivefromtime) then op.oldorganizationidentifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!

```
select  
case when (effectivethrutime is null and senttime >= effectivefromtime) then orgid  
when (effectivethrutime is not null and senttime >= effectivefromtime) then orgID  
when (effectivethrutime is not null and senttime between effectivethrutime and   effectivefromtime) then orgid  
end as orgid  
from ac  
left join op  
on ac.clinicalidentifier=op.clinicalidentifier  
where ac.senttime>op.effectivefromtime   
and ac.senttime<=isnull(op.effectivethrutime,ac.senttime)
```

This works as of now.
Let me know if I need to make any corrections.
Thanks
vihar

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    FirstTable.OrgID NewOrgID,
    SecondTable.OrgID
FROM
    FirstTable
    LEFT JOIN SecondTable 
        ON FirstTable.ClinicalID = SecondTable.ClinicalIndetifier 
        AND FirstTable.SentTime > SecondTable.EffectiveFromTime 
        AND FirstTable.SentTime < SecondTable.EffectiveThruTime
)
UPDATE CTE
    SET NewOrgID = OrgID
```

I can't tell from your question what the table names are or how they are joined but I think that should do it. To test the CTE you should replace the entire `UPDATE` statement above with `SELECT * FROM CTE` and that will show you NULL for each NewOrgID, and OrgID will show you the value that will be populated in each row. If you want to be really sure you could modify the CTE so that it includes all columns from FirstTable and SecondTable.